# How to make this geocode request assign to the variable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to make use of google maps geocode to convert this address string into a LatLng object. I believe that because it's an asynchronous call, latlng gets assigned null. What can I do to make the variable assignment work the way I want it to?

```
var latlng = codeAddress(address)
alert("Lat/lng is: " + latlng);

function codeAddress(address) {
      geocoder.geocode( {'address':address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          return results[0].geometry.location;
        } else {
          alert("Geocode failed due to: " + status);
        }
      }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `geocode()` is asynchronous, as you also mention, there is no way to call it synchronously. So, `var latlng = codeAddress(address);` is **not possible**. You need to use the result of the geocoding inside the function itself. Consider:

```
var latlng = null;
function codeAddress(address) {
      geocoder.geocode( {'address':address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          latlng = results[0].geometry.location; // use latlng here ..., e.g.:
          alert("Lat/lng is: " + latlng);
        } else {
          alert("Geocode failed due to: " + status);
        }
      }); 
    }
```

The call `codeAddress(address)` assigns to the global variable `latlng`. However, the problem is that you do not know when the assignment happens. In the above case you would know only after the alert box appeared.

The general approach is to process the result of the geocoding inside the callback, e.g. to use the result to fill an HTML field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I'm trying to do is render a google map if the status code is successful, otherwise, I will not render the map at all. Is there a way to make a javascript function/assignment block until another has finished? Or perhaps I need to go about this a different way?

Comment: You can call your function inside the geocode callback, i.e. instead of `alert(latlng)` call your `render(latlng)`.